# Matplotlib: AttributeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'polar'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to plot one polar and one scatter. Here is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')

iterator = lidar.iter_scans()
line = ax.scatter([0, 0], [0, 0], s=5, color="xkcd:salmon")
ax.set_rmax(DMAX)
ax.grid(True)
data = []


def environment():
    for i, scan in enumerate(lidar.iter_scans(5000)):
        if i <= 100:
            if i > 2:
                data.extend(scan,)
        else:
            break

    lidar.stop()
    lidar.get_info()
    lidar.get_info()
    lidar.get_health()

env_variable= np.array([(np.radians(meas[1]), meas[2])
                        for meas in data])
theta= [eachValue[0] for eachValue in env_variable]

r= [eachValue[1] for eachValue in env_variable]

ax.polar(theta, r)
```

this last line`(ax.polar(theta, r) )` creates error. How can I plot this polar in the same graph or what is the best way to plot two graph in a same place

Comment: Did you mean to use `ax.plot(theta, r)`?

Comment: yes @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 0):

I think depends on the python version

Using python 3.9 works just fine

I did try python 3.6 and I got the error, but initialiazing in this way worked for me:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
```

without using the

```
ax1.polar(angles, values)
```